# jQuery addClass as long as at least one descendant has class

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, addclass

I'm trying to highlight a table row as long as a least one of its descendants (`a.selectable`) has a particular class (`selectedLink`). I've gotten the row to highlight as long as all of its `a.selectable` elements have the mentioned class, but **I can't get it to work if just one `a.selectable` element has the `selectedLink` class**, which is my goal.

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4WL/51/ On the second row, BOTH `a.selectable` elements must be clicked for the row to highlight, and I'd like it to work if any of the descendant `a.selectable` elements have the class `selectedLink`.

The table follows this format:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="selectable" href="joe@mail.com">Joe</a></td>
        <td>Joes Program</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="selectable" href="jane@mail.com">Jane</a></td>
        <td><a class="selectable" href="janeprogram@mail.com">Jane's Program</a></td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To highlight cells and rows, I'm using this jQuery:

```
$( 'a.selectable' ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //highlight link and rows
  $( this ).toggleClass( 'selectedLink' );
  $( this ).parents( 'tr' ).has( 'a.selectedLink' ).removeClass( 'selectedRow' );
  $( this ).parents( 'tr' ).has( 'a.selectedLink' ).addClass( 'selectedRow' );
  $( this ).parents( 'tr' ).has( 'a:not( .selectedLink )' ).removeClass( 'selectedRow' );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, unlike [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) returns a `jQuery` object (*not boolean*), so you need to check it's length

```
$('a.selectable').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedLink');
    if ($(this).closest('tr').has('a.selectedLink').length)
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selectedRow');
    else
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4WL/53/)

Comment: Ah I understand, the need for `.length` was what was tripping me up.